# I am having a issue while running a terraform plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Error: This module is not yet installed. Run "terraform init" to install all modules
required by this configuration.

I tried terraform init even after that i see the same issue.

These is the output of terraform show

````
Reason: Backend configuration changed for "s3"

The "backend" is the interface that Terraform uses to store state,
perform operations, etc. If this message is showing up, it means that the
Terraform configuration you're using is using a custom configuration for
the Terraform backend.

Changes to backend configurations require reinitialization. This allows
Terraform to setup the new configuration, copy existing state, etc. This is
only done during "terraform init". Please run that command now then try again.

If the change reason above is incorrect, please verify your configuration
hasn't changed and try again. At this point, no changes to your existing
configuration or state have been made.

Failed to load backend: Initialization required. Please see the error message above.```

Could someone help to resolve the issue.
````

Comment: What's your backend block look like?

Comment: ```terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket    = "sandbox-terraform"
    key       = "terraform.tfstate"
    region    = "us-east-1"
    profile   = "test"
  }
}``` @CarloMencarelli

Comment: Thanks. And what does a `terraform init` return?

Comment: `
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.
If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your environment. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.`

Answer (score 0):

Is the bucket name correct? "sandbox-terraform" sounds like a generic bucket name.

Also, if you're using "test" as the profile name, then you'll have to ensure that there is a profile "test" in the AWS credentials file. Alternately, omit the profile attribute in your backend config.